# Change Icon of Icon-Widget dynamically in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am new to Flutter and I wanted to create a speech to text application.
Therefore I want a Button, whos icon changes depending if the a variable is true or false.
I am using a floatingActionButton:

```
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      print(_isListening);
      _isListening = !_isListening;
    },
    child: Icon(_isListening ? Icons.mic_rounded : Icons.mic_rounded ),
  ),
```

And the first line of my code is the definition of my variable:

```
bool _isListening = false;
```

The "print(_isListening) is giving me the desired output in the console, but in the app, nothing changes.
Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure it's a StatefulWidget and use **setState()** to notify the framework that the internal state of this object has changed. Calling setState notifies the framework that the internal state of this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface in this subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a build for this State object. Please see the code below:

```
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      print(_isListening);
      setState(()=>_isListening = !_isListening);
    },
    child: Icon(_isListening ? Icons.mic_rounded : Icons.mic_off),
  ),
```

Full working code below :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyWidget());
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget();

  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool _isListening = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text("Flutter Demo"),
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print(_isListening);
            setState(()=>_isListening = !_isListening);
          },
          child: Icon(_isListening ? Icons.mic_rounded : Icons.mic_off),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Also just noticed that you are using the same icon in both true and false cases. Please change the icon ==> Icon(_isListening ? Icons.mic_rounded : Icons.mic_off),

Comment: Yeah, thank you, changing those two things did it for me! Thanks a lot mate :)

Comment: Please like and accept the answer if it help solve your issue :)